# Why is water vapor released when an empty water bottle is squeezed?

Tags: everyday-life, pressure

I recently came across this tutorial and wondered why vapor will come out when the cap comes off. [Heres the Tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Water-Bottle-Cap-Pop-off-with-Air-Pressure)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the cap bursts off the bottle the air inside it will expand rapidly and [adiabatically, so its temperature will fall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_process#Adiabatic_heating_and_cooling). If there is enough water vapour in the air inside the bottle, and if the temperature reduction takes the temperature below the [dew point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dew_point), the water vapour will condense giving the fine mist that you see.

In this case it looks to me (it's hard to tell for sure) as if there were droplets of water left inside the water bottle, in which case the air inside was saturated with water vapour. Under those circumstances even a modest temperature reduction will cause condensation of the water vapour.